# Should a single page fetcher like TinEye obey robots.txt?

Tags: robots.txt

I've noticed that tineye.com does not attempt to fetch "robots.txt" from my website. It also sends a "user agent" string consisting of the user's browser with "TinEye/1.0 (via http://www.tineye.com/)" tagged on to the end.

Is this correct behaviour? If I write something which fetches one file from a web site, at the user's discretion, is it acceptable to not fetch "robots.txt"? Or should any automated program always obey robots.txt?

Please note **this is not a question about tineye.com**.

Answer (score 3):

Using robots.txt is only ever voluntary, there's no international law that says you should.

Comment: I pointed them to my web site and checked the log immediately afterwards, and there was no record of them looking at it.

Comment: PS this doesn't answer the question, it should have been a comment.

Comment: You asked if it was correct behaviour. The answer is there is no law that says if people should. I've taken out the bit about TinEye saying they do read it.